# Creating os.FileInfo struct for Readdir mock response

Tags: go

I'm trying to mock out the os.Readdir method to test reading some directory information without having the directory actually formed how the tests require. I'm trying to create a slice of FileInfo objects, which is the return value of os.Readdir, however when I try to create a FileInfo object I'm unable to actually set its values. I see a "New" function in the fileinfo package, but it doesn't appear to be usable when I am actually trying to call it.

I've also tried instantiating a FileInfo object like this (both using os.FileInfo and fs.FileInfo), but I've had no luck with any of it. Is there something simple I'm missing, or is there something strange with interfaces or something in Go that is preventing me from instantiating the object as I would any other?

```
os.FileInfo{
  Name: "test",
  Size: 100,
}
```

Comment: Interfaces are not structs. Please take the Tour of Go for basic language fundamentals. Just provide something that implements fs.Fileinfo.

Answer (score 0):

[`fs.FileInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FileInfo) is an interface, not a struct. You would need to declare your own concrete type that implements all of its methods, for example:

```golang
package test_pkg

type fakeFileInfo struct {
  name string
  size int64
  // ...
}

func (info *fakeFileInfo) Name() string {
  return info.name;
}

func (info *fakeFileInfo) Size() int64 {
  return info.size;
}

// ...
```